# Sidekiq retries: How to refresh workers / code?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sidekiq

in my sidekiq there are 4 jobs, that stopped by exceptions and now are in retries.

I fixed the code, but how i can now start a retry with the fixed code.
If i manually restart the job, it has the old code / exception.
I dont want to lose the job.

If i restart sidekiq, then all queues and retries are lost?

Thank in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can/must restart sidekiq to make code changes visible to it. Redis holding job information and query, not sidekiq.

P.S. In most cases all be ok, [but sometimes](https://github.com/mperham/sidekiq/issues/3637)

Answer (score 0):

You just need to restart all the jobs. Those are queued and safe unless you clear them or any other code clear them. All the data is being stored in redis and hence they are in safe place for the moment.